# How to prevent SpringBootTest stop server before async methods finished?

Tags: asynchronous, mockito, integration-testing, mockmvc, spring-boot-test

I have code like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Result createModel(DataModel model) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> doSomeThing(model));
    return new Result("your request has been recieved successfully");      
}
```

and i try to write integration test like

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
 @ActiveProfiles("integration_tests, linux")
 @Transactional
 public class DataServiceTestIT {
    @AutoWired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    this.mockMvc.perform(post('/create')).andExcpect(status().isOk());

    assertEquals(1, JdbcTestUtil.countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "data_model_table));
 }
```

When back-side received request, will response successful message immediately, real jobs is processed asynchronously.
After response is sent, server is stopped and i can't test doSomeThing code.(My real code is more complicated and there are multiple async parts)

How to prevent server stopping or waiting other methods finsihing. My controller don't return callable result. When process finished, send notifications to users. I try to use get MvcResult.getAsyncResult() but i think that it is not suitable for this.

Answer (score 1):

To wait for completing method, i use CompletableFuture and doAnswer with callRealMethod.

```
    @AutoWired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    @SpyBean
    private DoSomethingService doSomethingService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();

    CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    doAnswer((invocation) -> {
       invocation.callRealMethod();
       cf.complete("method finished");
       return null;
    }).when(doSomethingService).doSomethingMetod();
    this.mockMvc.perform(post('/create')).andExcpect(status().isOk());
    cf.get(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    assertEquals(1, JdbcTestUtil.countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, 
        "data_model_table));
}
```